# Time complexity of nested for-loop with two independent variables

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I am trying to calculate the time complexity of this function:

```
int fun1(A, k){      //A is an array, k is an integer
n = length(A);       //length of array
for j:= 1 to k{
    for i:= j to n{
        if A[i] < A[j-1]{
            x:=  A[j-1]; 
            A[j-1]:= A[i]; 
            A[i]:= x
        }
    }
}
return A[k-1]}
```

We iterate *k* times in the outer loop, but how to calculate number of iterations of inner loop, and then the time complexity of entire algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the work inside the double loop is constant and assuming that k<=n then the complexity can be written as

[image]

Edit: I forgot the constant but it doesn't matter as it will disappear inside the big Oh notation

Comment: How did you recive from (sum C, i = j to n) to (n - j + 1)? It should not be (n - j + 1)(n + j)? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Since C is constant you factor it out then the inner sum becomes sum(i=j to n) of 1 which is (n-j+1). For example, sum(3 to 5) of 1 is 1+1+1=3=(5-3+1)